# Apache http proxy - change outgoing ip

Tags: centos, proxy, ip

I have centos dedicted server with 5 assigned ip addresses.
eth0 - ip 1
eth0:1 - ip 2
eth0:2 - ip 3
eth0:3 - ip 4
eth0:4 - ip 5

I have apache with proxy enabled. I can connect to the proxy using any ip and port 80 but the proxy will always use eth0 ip as an outgoing proxy ip.

Can I configure it to use the others ip ?

I want to connect to for example third ip and I would like the proxy to use that ip for my outgoing requests.

Comment: Configure outgoing address in your proxy's configfile.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell apache what address to use as the source address when connecting to a backend. Use the `ProxySourceAddress` directive for this.

More info at [the official apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxysourceaddress).